# How to fill blank spaces in jQuery UI sortable Dashboard

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable, dashboard

I am trying to create a Dashboard for my project with draggable cards which can be repositioned accordingly. I am facing an issue when there are cards of different heights.

[image: Normal Screen]

Small cards in the top row are initially arranged horizontally but I am not able to reposition these cards in a way that the 4 small cards should be on the left side in 2 rows of 2 cards each and add a bigger card on the right side of the page. When I try to do that it appears like this

[image: Smaller cards doesn't fill the available space]

What I am trying to achieve here is,

[image: Expected result]

How can I make these cards to fill up the available space?

Im using Bootstrap5, jQuery-ui 1.13, jQuery 3.6

Code Samples below, ( removed contents for readability)

**HTML**

```
<main class="content">
        <div class="container-fluid p-0">
        <div id="sortable" class="row ui-sortable">
            
            <div class="col-sm-3" id="tapcard1">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header header-pad">
                            small card1
                        </div>
                        <hr class="dark horizontal my-0">
                        <div class="card-footer">
                            <span class="text-success text-sm font-weight-bolder">+3.5%</span> than lask week
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3" id="tapcard2">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header header-pad">
                            small card2
                        </div>
                        <hr class="dark horizontal my-0">
                        <div class="card-footer">
                            <span class="text-success text-sm font-weight-bolder">+12.7%</span> than lask week
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3" id="tapcard3">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header header-pad">
                            small card3
                        </div>
                        <hr class="dark horizontal my-0">
                        <div class="card-footer">
                            <span class="text-danger text-sm font-weight-bolder">-0.5%</span> than lask week
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3" id="tapcard4">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header header-pad">
                            small card4
                        </div>
                        <hr class="dark horizontal my-0">
                        <div class="card-footer">
                            <span class="text-success text-sm font-weight-bolder">+6.2%</span> than lask week
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            
                <div id="card5" class="col-sm-6"  style="padding-bottom: -10px;">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="x_panel" >
                            <div class="x_title">
                                bigcard1
                            </div>

                            <div class="x_content">
                                
                                <!--//table-responsive-->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="card6" class="col-sm-6"  style="padding-bottom: -10px;">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="x_panel" >
                            <div class="x_title">
                                bigcard2
                            </div>

                            <div class="x_content">
                                
                                <!--//table-responsive-->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
```

**jQuery**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
        $("#sortable").sortable();
        $("#sortable").disableSelection();
  });
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I resolved it by adding class "**d-block**" to my "row" div and adding class "**float-start**" on each col div.

Here is your code with my solution :

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("#sortable").sortable();
  $("#sortable").disableSelection();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container-fluid p-0">
  <div id="sortable" class="row ui-sortable d-block">
   <div class="col-sm-6 float-start mb-2" id="tapcard1">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header header-pad">
          Big card1
        </div>
        <hr class="dark horizontal my-0">
        <div class="card-footer">
          <div class="text-success text-sm font-weight-bolder">+3.5%</div> than lask week
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 float-start mb-2" id="tapcard1">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header header-pad">
          small card1
        </div>
        <hr class="dark horizontal my-0">
        <div class="card-footer">
          <span class="text-success text-sm font-weight-bolder">+3.5%</span> than lask week
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 float-start mb-2" id="tapcard2">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header header-pad">
          small card2
        </div>
        <hr class="dark horizontal my-0">
        <div class="card-footer">
          <span class="text-success text-sm font-weight-bolder">+12.7%</span> than lask week
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 float-start mb-2" id="tapcard3">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header header-pad">
          small card3
        </div>
        <hr class="dark horizontal my-0">
        <div class="card-footer">
          <span class="text-danger text-sm font-weight-bolder">-0.5%</span> than lask week
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 float-start mb-2" id="tapcard4">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header header-pad">
          small card4
        </div>
        <hr class="dark horizontal my-0">
        <div class="card-footer">
          <span class="text-success text-sm font-weight-bolder">+6.2%</span> than lask week
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 float-start mb-2" id="tapcard1">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header header-pad">
          Big card1
        </div>
        <hr class="dark horizontal my-0">
        <div class="card-footer">
          <div class="text-success text-sm font-weight-bolder">+3.5%</div> than lask week
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works for horizontal spacing but not for vertical spacing as mentioned.

Comment: I never found a solution to this issue but achieved the desired by adding another hidden big card and appending all small cards to that big card on a button trigger.